# why is laravel not displaying the blade?

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, websocket, response

I'm currently following a tutorial about laravel's websocket.
i did exactly like the tutorial but....
here's the code
the controller:

```
class CommentController extends Controller{
public function getcomments(Post $post){
    return response()->json($post->comments()->with('user')->latest()->get());

}
public function addcomment(Request $req,Post $post){
   $comment=$post->comment()->create([
       'body'=>$req->body,
       'user_id'=>auth::id()
   ]);
   $comment=Comment::where('id',$comment->id)->with('user')->first();
    return $comment->toJson;
}}
```

the routes/api file

```
Route::get('/post/{post}', 'CommentController@getcomments');
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
      Route::post('/post/{post}', 'CommentController@addcomment');});
```

in the tutorial when he goes to /post/1 it displays the html code in the post.blade.php

here's what i get from that
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDQqD.png)

help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your tutorial video ask you to access `/post/1` but `/api/post/1` is what you did. The API probably is used for fetching all the comments of post with `id:1` which is located at `/post/1`.

Comment: 1/the methods name have to be index() not getcomments() (i wonder how it worked for him)   . 2/ as u said ,its /post/id .   its working now so thank you